# Why the For-Each loop not working in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have to create a PowerShell to read a CSV file, do some process and export the result back to a CSV. But after importing the CSV the file is not looping. The first item only processed in my script, other items are not looping. I tried `foreach` and `ForEach-Object` to loop the file.

```
$AddUsers = Import-Csv $FilePath\Ticket_Template_Test.csv
Invoke-Command -ArgumentList($AddUsers) -ScriptBlock {
    Param ([PSCustomObject[]]$AddUserDetails)
    foreach ($User in $AddUserDetails) {
        try {
            $Username = $User.PreferredUserName.Trim()
            Write-Host $Username
            $Firstname = $User.FirstName.Trim()
            $Lastname = $User.LastName.Trim()
            $DisplayName = $Firstname + " " + $Lastname
```

Loop all the items in CSV.

Comment: [1] do not use `Invoke-Command` for this. it adds needless complexity. [*grin*] [2] **_please_** post the 1st few rows of your input CSV, what changes you intend, and what the output CSV for those rows should look like. right now, your code makes no sense to me ... [*blush*]

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete and doesn't even attempt to write anything back to a CSV. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it still exposes the problem you're trying to debug, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code along with sample input and all errors you're getting from that code.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, here's my guess.  Understanding the basics wins over copying and pasting.  The fields in the csv have a lot of trailing spaces?

```
import-csv file.csv | foreach {  
  $Username = $_.PreferredUserName.Trim()
  $Firstname = $_.FirstName.Trim()
  $Lastname = $_.LastName.Trim()
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Username = $Username
    Firstname = $Firstname
    Lastname = $Lastname
    DisplayName = $Firstname + " " + $Lastname
  }
} | export-csv file2.csv
```